# finding DBID in V$sql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I  would like to extract some Metadata from V$

The most interessting information are in `V$SQL`, but unfortunatly there is no `DBID` in it.

How can I extract `DBID` with other infos in `V$SQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the view **V#DATABASE**.

```
SQL> SELECT DBID FROM V$DATABASE;

      DBID
----------
1384408790
```

Another way is to connect to the target database using **RMAN** which will show you the **DBID**:

```
RMAN> connect target sys@pdborcl

target database Password:
connected to target database: ORCL (DBID=1384408790)
```

> How can I extract DBID with other infos in V$SQL?

`V$SQL` and `V$DATABASE` are two different views and are used for completely different purpose. The former is used for **session-level** info, while the latter is for **database-level** info.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to join `V$DATABASE` and `V$SQL`

Comment: Join for doing what? Why do you need `V$SQL`? What is your desired output?

Comment: SQL_FULLTEXT and SQL_ID are session level info, while DBID is database level info. Two completely different things, so you need to use two different views.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much